# How to get column width from GridView?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

Just as the title suggests, I wish to get the width of each of the columns after I call DataBind().

Calling gv.Columns[i].ItemStyle.Width.Value returns 0. This is probably because the GridView's definition in the .aspx file doesn't define the width. I don't want to define it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to get the width of the columns as they are rendered on the client? Subject to such things as the width of the content, CSS settings elsewhere in the page, and the browser window size?

To do that, you'll have to use some client-side code, and either gather up the widths and store them in a hidden field, waiting for postback, or send them back via Ajax.

Either way, this will be a two-step process:  you won't be able to `DataBind` and then check what the width will be in the same page load. You'll have to wait for the page to be rendered on the client in order to determine the true width.

In any case, unless you formally set the `ItemStyle.Width`, you won't have a non-zero value for it, either right after `DataBind` or after postback, because the width of the column *as rendered on the client* isn't something that automatically gets updated on postback.  My suggestions, above, all involve determining the value on the client side and returning it in some other way.